# need .htaccess rewrite rule for hot linking images

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site that is hotlinking images, please help

```
<img src="http://mattdunlap.org/?ak_action=api_record_view&id=1060&type=feed" alt="">
```

Since it is not an image (jpg|png|gif), my hotlinking script is not working

I've tried this but doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?cheaps1.info/.*$ [NC]    
RewriteRule \.(feed)$ http://www.mattdunlap.org/images/dick.gif [R,L]
```

I've also thought about using the PHP gd library on my index page with a conditional $_GET, but would like to do everything with .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?cheaps1.info/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} feed$
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.mattdunlap.org/images/dick.gif [R,L]
```

The first operand of `RewriteRule` does not include the query string. You have to use `%{QUERY_STRING}`, `%{REQUEST_URI}` or similar.

Comment: Sorry, but it just isn't working... I was able to do a normal hotlink protection for jpg, gif, or png, but since this does not have a file extension, hotlinking doesn't work

Comment: @Matt I'd forgotten to remove the dot before. Also, if this is in a .htaccess the rewriterule should be changed to ^$ in order to match the root of the website.